# Difference between "Class#message" and "Class.message" notation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is a very basic ruby question.  What is the difference between `ClassName#message` and `ClassName.message`?

I am reading a basic Ruby guide and I see both references used quite a lot.  It seems that mainly in the code `ClassName.message` is used but in the documentation `ClassName#message` is used.

Is the `#` simply documentation convention? Will only the `.` work for message passing in actual code?  Or is there something that I am just missing?

Does the meaning differ in Rails at all?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In code you use `object.method`. In documentation however, `Class#method` denotes an instance method (e.g. `String#upcase`), whereas `Class.method` or `Class::method` denotes a class/module method (e.g. `Math.log10`).

Comment: Glad to help. One more piece of advice since you are new here: it's StackOverflow etiquette to accept the most helpful answer with the little tick mark below the downvote button.

Comment: Don't worry, I know.  Stack wouldn't let me select an answer for a few more minutes when I wanted to accept your answer.

Comment: It wasn't about my answer per se, just your account seemed rather new  and I always try to turn new users into good SO citizens.

Answer (score 4):

The `#` is used in the documentations to point out the difference between class methods and instance methods.

In the code, you'll be using `.` in all the cases.

Comment: What about in Rails.  If my memory serves me right I remember there being a `view#page` or something to that effect line in many controllers.  How does that work?

Comment: That syntax is particular to Rails and its routes file. It's not Ruby code.

Comment: You probably refer to the syntax in the routes file (`controller#action`).

Answer (score -1):

'#' is rails convention. In rails className#Message will map to Message action of your className controller.

```
Ex:
   match "profile" => "users#show"
```

This will map root_path/profile => Show method(or action) of UserController.

Comment: No, it's not a Rails convention, it's a Ruby convention that Rails uses for what method should be routed to.

Comment: Since I am from RoR background, I thought it was rails convention, Thanks @AndrewMarshall for educating me..

Comment: @MichaelPapile It never denotes an instance variable. In both cases it's used to denote an instance method.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Yes you are correct, I mis-typed that, meant method. I deleted it to avoid confusion.